# Compile ACE in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: c++, ace

How do I compile ACE on Ubuntu 9.10.
What environment variables do I need to set?

Answer (score 2):

See the section on building ACE on Unix platforms the "traditional way" in the [`ACE-INSTALL.html`](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#unix_traditional) document that is shipped with the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) distribution.

***EDIT***: Make sure you use the [latest version of ACE](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/).

Comment: He seems to be speaking of "Advanced Cluster Environment"
not "Adaptative Communication Environment"

Comment: @f4: Ah, I didn't notice the tag.  My mistake.

Comment: @f4, the tag wasn't added by the OP.  Most likely he *is* looking for "Adaptive Communication Environment".

Comment: @f4: Hmm, it looks like the OP was talking about ACE the "Adaptive Communication Environment", not the cluster environment.  The down-vote is no longer justified. :)

Comment: Yep, sorry I didn't notice the tag was added by someone else -- edit: Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but that package seems to [include](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/i386/libace-dev/filelist) all the necessary header files and the shared library.  You should not have to build anything yourself.  Have you tried using the library yet?